# Aligning Point Cloud with IMU Heading in Sensor Fusion Setup

Tags: imu, pointcloud, lidar, sensor-fusion, laser-scan-matcher

I'm currently working on a sensor fusion setup involving an IMU that provides absolute orientation with respect to True North and an Ouster Lidar generating PointCloud2 data. The IMU publishes to the topic /imu/data with frame_id base_link, while the Lidar data is available on topic /ouster/points with frame_id os_sensor.

In my fusion process, I've successfully integrated IMU data with pose_with_covariance and GPS to generate local odometry. However, I'm encountering an issue where the point cloud doesn't align with the IMU heading after fusion. The point cloud still aligns with the initial pose, and the heading in the pose_with_covariance remains at the initial orientation.

My goal is to align the point cloud with the heading provided by the IMU. Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this alignment within my fusion setup?